# Связь табличной части с документом

Tags: 1с, sql

Добрый вечер, сообщество!

**1С Предприятие 8.2 (8.2.15.289)**

**Суть проблемы:**
Есть документ. У документа есть табличная часть. Нужно написать запрос, в результате которого выводятся только те документы (вместе с табличной частью), у которых хотя бы в одной строке табличной части поле "дата" соответствует определенному условию (больше введенной пользователем даты). Причем строки ТЧ должны выводиться все, не зависимо от удовлетворения условия.

Вот, например, есть документ, у него в ТЧ 20 записей. Только одна запись имеет нужную нам дату. На выходе имеем:

```
Документ_№1  
  Запись_ТЧ_№1
  Запись_ТЧ_№2
  ...
  Запись_ТЧ_№20

следующий документ
...
```

Каким образом это можно сделать?

---

Пробовал отобрать все документы, и с помощью ЛЕВОГО СОЕДИНЕНИЯ объединить их с ихними табличными частями, но у ТЧ нету ссылки на документ. И каким образом ТЧ связана с документом я не понимаю. Так что эта идея отпала.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У табличной части есть ссылка на документ. Чтоб с табличной частью выборку сделать вложенный запрос с различными надо делать. Как-то так:

```
 "ВЫБРАТЬ
 |  Док.Ссылка,
 |  Док.ТабЧасть.(
 |      Ссылка,
 |      НомерСтроки,
 |      ....
 |  )
 |ИЗ
 |  (ВЫБРАТЬ РАЗЛИЧНЫЕ
 |      ДокТабЧасть.Ссылка КАК Ссылка
 |  ИЗ
 |      Документ.Док.ТабЧасть КАК ДокТабЧасть
 |  ГДЕ
 |      ДокТабЧасть.Дата > &Дата) КАК Ссылки
 |      ВНУТРЕННЕЕ СОЕДИНЕНИЕ Документ.Док КАК Док
 |      ПО Ссылки.Ссылка = Док.Ссылка"
```

Comment: супер, спасибо